# What's the maximum length for AAD in GCM?

Tags: aes, implementation, gcm

```
int mbedtls_gcm_starts( mbedtls_gcm_context *ctx,
                int mode,
                const unsigned char *iv,
                size_t iv_len,
                const unsigned char *add,
                size_t add_len )
{
    int ret;
    unsigned char work_buf[16];
    size_t i;
    const unsigned char *p;
    size_t use_len, olen = 0;

    /* IV and AD are limited to 2^64 bits, so 2^61 bytes */
    if( ( (uint64_t) iv_len  ) >> 61 != 0 ||
        ( (uint64_t) add_len ) >> 61 != 0 )
    {
        return( MBEDTLS_ERR_GCM_BAD_INPUT );
    }
}
```

Above is a part of the implementation of [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) (Galois/Counter Mode) by `mbedtls`.

The implementation puts a restriction on the length of `AAD` (additional authenticated data), that is, the length of `AAD` cannot be greater than $2^{61}$ bytes.

My questions:

1. **Is there an actual limit on the length of `AAD`, or that's just an implementaion-specific restriction?**
2. **Theoretically, can I input an `AAD` of any length?**

Comment: Note that the security of GHash decays with increasing message length and becomes unacceptably weak long before you hit this hard limit.

Comment: That's oy true for the message length and not the AAD length, correct?

Comment: @mat That is incorrect. GHASH operates on both the additional data and the cipherext and it does so in the way for both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [GCM specification](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/gcm/gcm-spec.pdf):

> Additional authenticated data (AAD), which is denoted as A. This data is authenticated, but not encrypted, and can have any number of bits between $0$ and $2^{64}$ .